# SwiftUI Not able to find image in Bundle but the image is in the correct path?

Tags: ios, swiftui, bundle

I am attempting to load images from the a bundle in my project. Instead I get the following error:

`2020-03-20 11:38:53.032321-0400 Journey[4626:1025739] [SwiftUI] No image named 'CountryPicker.bundle/Images/AF.png' found in asset catalog for main bundle (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/720B947B-209E-4527-AE1C-B73D905D3D35/Journey.app)`

As you can see in the screenshot, the image is in the bundle:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Picker(selection: $countryOrigin, label: Text("Country of Origin")) {

    Section(header: SearchBar(text: $fetcher.searchQuery)) {

        List(fetcher.country) { country in

            HStack() {

                Image("CountryPicker.bundle/Images/\(country.id).png")


                Text(country.name)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this!?

***UPDATE***

[image]

Comment: @Asperi where did all your comments go!?

Comment: i assume has deleted them.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you move image to xcAssets, it works. You can also call Image(uiImage(named: "imageName.png")!)

Comment: its a bundle not images.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, SwiftUI's `Image` appears to only work with XCAsset catalogs. I had a use case where I couldn't use XCAsset catalogs easily, so I made this workaround View:

```
struct ImageWithoutCatalog: View, UIViewRepresentable {
    var name: String
    var bundle: Bundle

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, with: nil))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
        uiView.image = UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, with: nil)
    }
}
```